# how to combine two variable column-by-column in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have two variables, multi-line.

```
VAR1="1
2
3
4"

VAR2="ao
ad
af
ae"
```

I want to get

```
VAR3="1ao
2ad
3af
4ae"
```

I know I can do it by:

```
echo "$VAR1" > /tmp/order
echo "$VAR2" | paste /tmp/order  -
```

But is there any way to do without a temp file?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`paste <(echo "$VAR1") <(echo "$VAR2") --delimiters ''`

Comment: what's the <() operator called?

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum "<()" is called a "process substitution". Not all shells support it, but most popular ones do: https://www.google.com/search?q=process+substitution

Comment: This is not working for me in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS). The paste line gives the following error: script.sh: 11: script.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected.

Comment: On OSX, I had to do `paste --d '' <(echo "$VAR1") <(echo "$VAR2")`. Using either the `--delimiters` arg, or putting it at the end of the command gave me errors about  `No such file or directory`.

Comment: I was having the same problem as @iamyojimbo on macOS and using `--d` gave me `paste: illegal option -- -
usage: paste [-s] [-d delimiters] file ...` . Using `-d` resolved it

Answer (score 4):

You can say:

```
$ VAR3=$(paste <(echo "$VAR1") <(echo "$VAR2"))
$ echo "$VAR3"
1   ao
2   ad
3   af
4   ae
```

It's not clear whether you want spaces in the resulting array or not.  Your example *that works* would contain spaces as in the above case.

If you don't want spaces, i.e. `1ao` instead of `1    ao`, then you can say:

```
$ VAR3=$(paste <(echo "$VAR1") <(echo "$VAR2") -d '')
$ echo "$VAR3"
1ao
2ad
3af
4ae
```