# Linux Shell, Awk : Merge 2 Variable Data by Column

Tags: linux, bash, awk

The left part data (in variable) like :

```
 echo "$lpart"

 "2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-39dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55"
 "2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-39dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55"
 "2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-39dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55"
 "2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-37dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55"
```

The right part data (in variable) like :

```
echo "$rpart"     

"qhy2"
"qhy2"
"Apple Setup"
"qhy2"
```

I would like to merge the 2 data by column, it is :

```
 "2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-39dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55"  "qhy2"
 "2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-39dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55"  "qhy2"
 "2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-39dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55"  "Apple Setup"
 "2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-37dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55"  "qhy2"
```

This request is the same as the post : [how to combine two variable column-by-column in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437124/how-to-combine-two-variable-column-by-column-in-bash), but my busybox does not support paste command.
I have tried the commands :

```
 awk 'BEGIN{print ARGV[1], ARGV[2]}' "$lpart"  "$rpart"
 awk -v awk_lpart="$lpart" -v awk_rpart="$rpart" 'BEGIN{print awk_lpart awk_rpart }'
```

those will merge by row..

Could you give me suggestion how I could achieve the request ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[FNR]=$1; next} {print $0, a[FNR]}' <(echo "$rpart") <(echo "$lpart")
"2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-39dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55" "qhy2"
"2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-39dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55" "qhy2"
"2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-39dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55" "Apple
"2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-37dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55" "qhy2"
```

Comment: Thanks,  that is, the braces {} would respond to the introduced(<) data respectively ?

Comment: `<(...)` is process substitution. You must use `bash` for this.

Comment: Thank your suggestion, it works. Is the way for multi-variables also?

Comment: You can insert 2 variables at a time and then save the output in a new  variable. After that you can run same awk command between new variable and 3rd var.

Answer (score 1):

Building on one of your attempts:

```
awk -v awk_lpart="$lpart" -v awk_rpart="$rpart" 'BEGIN{
    split(awk_lpart,lp,/\n/)
    split(awk_rpart,rp,/\n/)
    for (i=1; i in lp; i++) {
        print lp[i], rp[i]
    }
}'
"2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-39dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55" "qhy2"
"2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-39dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55" "qhy2"
"2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-39dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55" "Apple Setup"
"2017-07-03 13:39:5", "-37dB", "7c:e9:d3:f1:61:55" "qhy2"
```

That will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.